# Class Initializer list does not work with copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I have this class A with one variable, initializing variables using initializer list works totally fine, if no copy constructor is present.

```
class A {
    public:
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    A a = {2};
    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

However if I do have a copy constructor inside the class, I am getting an error

```
main.cpp:23:13: error: could not convert ‘{2}’ from ‘’ to ‘A’
     A a = {2};
```

Code :

```
class A {
    public:
    int x;
    A(A& v)
    {
        printf("Copied");
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a = {2};
    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

Why is it so?

Comment: Is there a workaround for the same?

Comment: This is not a copy constructor.

Comment: is it necessary for a copy constructor to copy the elements, I don't think so

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, It unfortunately is. A non-const reference [still qualifies](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor).

Comment: No, it's not necessary. But this is still not a copy constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user-declared constructor `A::A(A&)` makes `A` not an aggregate, then it can't be [aggregate-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) from brace-init-list like `{2}` again.

You can add a constructor taking `int`, e.g.

```
class A {
    public:
    int x;
    A(int x) : x(x) {}
    A(const A& v)
    {
        printf("Copied");
    }
};
```

Then

```
A a = {2}; // list-initialize a from {2} by constructor A::A(int)
```

---

BTW: Copy constructor takes `const T&` conventionally.

Comment: But if you see now, we have the temp object on the right side which is going to be copied to `a` object, shouldn't the copy constructor also be called, if not why?

Comment: @PulkitBhatnagar The select constructor (i.e. `A::A(int)`) would be used directly to initialize `a`, see [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

Comment: Couldn't understand from the doc, could you please brief the same here

Comment: @PulkitBhatnagar *If the previous stage does not produce a match, all constructors of T participate in overload resolution against the set of arguments that consists of the elements of the braced-init-list*, so at this stage, the constructor taking `int` (against `2`) is selected to construct the object directly; copy constructor doesn't take part in.